# how to perform a silent install of bandwidthD in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apt, software-installation

how to perform a silent install of [bandwidthD](http://bandwidthd.sourceforge.net/) to avoid windows and put IP and interfaces to monitor by command line (for ubuntu 20.04)

```
sudo apt-get install bandwidthd # with what parameters
```

Important:

There is not `help bandwidthd`. Only help:

```
bandwidthd --help

Usage: bandwidthd [OPTION]

Options:
    -D      Do not fork to background
    -l      List detected devices
    -c filename Alternate configuration file
    --help      Show this help
```

thanks

**Update:**

I found a workaround, and at @muru's suggestion I post it as an answer. If there is a better answer, feel free to post it and I will select it as the best answer.

Comment: Are you posting both the problem and solution in the question? If so, please post the solution as an answer

Comment: not really an answer. it is a workaround. but you are right. solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install bandwidthd
```

After installed, if necessary, edit the configuration file and change the default parameters.

```
# default parameters:
sudo debconf-show bandwidthd
  bandwidthd-pgsql/sensorid:
  bandwidthd/dev: any
  bandwidthd/promisc: false
  bandwidthd/metarefresh:
  bandwidthd/subnet: 169.254.0.0/16, 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.122.0/24
  bandwidthd/outputcdf: true
  bandwidthd/recovercdf: true

sudo nano /etc/bandwidthd/bandwidthd.conf
# change default parameters. Example:

subnet 192.168.0.0/16
dev "wlp1s0"

# save the changes and...

sudo /etc/init.d/bandwidthd restart
```

access:

```
http://localhost/bandwidthd/
```